# How can i edit button label 0 to 1 when pressed button on Discord.JS v14

Tags: discord.js

```
 if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

    const pol = await polls.findOne({ message: interaction.message.id });

    if (!pol) return;

    await interaction.deferReply({
        ephemeral: true
    });

    if (pol.voters.includes(interaction.user.id)) return interaction.editReply({
        embeds: [{
            color: 0xff0000,
            title: "❌ Already Voted!"
        }]
    });

    pol.votes = pol.votes || {};

    if (pol.votes[interaction.customId]) pol.votes[interaction.customId] += 1
    else pol.votes[interaction.customId] = 1;

    pol.voters.push(interaction.user.id);

    await polls.findOneAndUpdate({ message: pol.message }, pol);

    interaction.editReply({
        embeds: [{
            color: 0x008000,
            title: "✅ Voted Successfully"
        }]
    });
},};


    const m = interaction.message;


    m.edit({
        components: m.components?.map(row => {
            row.components = row.components?.map(v => {
                v.label = `${pol.votes[v.customId] || 0}`;

                return v;
            });

            return row;
        })
    })
```

How can i edit button label 0 to 1 when pressed button on Discord.JS v14

This code is not working

I converted this code V13 to v14 but don't worked. How can i fix it? Looked guide but i don't understand it

Comment: I'm assuming you've merged code from your interaction event handler and your button event handler. If that is the case, please create two separate code blocks, one showing the slash command hander and the other showing the button handler.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same button twice, but change its label while editing.

Reviewing your code, you're not really sending any components with the message. Try the code below.

```js
const button = new ButtonBuilder().setLabel("0").setStyle(ButtonStyle.PRIMARY).setCustomId("test");

interaction.reply({
    content: "Hello World",
    components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(button)]
});

// inside the collector, to edit the label
interaction.editReply({
    components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(button.setLabel("1"))]
})
```